# How can I use a List inside a method?

Tags: .net, list, methods, this

Here's a List<> that is inside a method

```
public void MenuList()
{
    List<string> flavors = new List<string>();
    flavors.Add("Angus Steakhouse");
    flavors.Add("Belly Buster");
    flavors.Add("Pizza Bianca");
}
```

Now, I put a new method

```
public int GetSizePrices(int num)
{
   this.MenuList ???    
}
```

How can I use the flavor object inside GetSizePrices method?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want your `GetSizePrices()` method to do to the flavors object?

Comment: Just read and use it inside the GetSizePrices() method. I guess the first answer is what I am looking for.

Comment: A more important question is that should flavors ever change?  Or should the method MenuList() be exclusive in charge of creating and delivering that list to all other methods?  Most specifically can you update your question to show what you are ACTUALLY trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, If I can't say much about my question. I'm just starting to learn it and some terms I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like?:

```
public Class SomeClass
{
  public IEnumerable<string> MenuList()
  {
    List<string> flavors = new List<string>();
    flavors.Add("Angus Steakhouse");
    flavors.Add("Belly Buster");
    flavors.Add("Pizza Bianca");
    return flavors;
  }

  public int GetSizePrices(int num)
  {
   // No idea what to do with num
   return this.MenuList().Count();
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 The OP is obviously new to C#, and this doesn't explain how to put `flavors` into a field (or property) that is then accessible to other methods in the same class.

Comment: I agree with your assertion that it doesn't explain how it is doing it, but I'd also argue that the OP question is ambiguous, and this answer at a general level does access the flavors object.

Answer (score 0):

There obviously many different ways to accomplish this and will be based on your design requirements.

For now lets assume you are new to C# and you might consider these two simple ways to get you started on your journey (I purposefully left out idiomatic C# to get as familiar to your existing code as possible).

**Option 1 - Pass it in as parameter:**

```
public List<string> BuildMenuList()
{
    List<string> flavors = new List<string>();
    flavors.Add("Angus Steakhouse");
    flavors.Add("Belly Buster");
    flavors.Add("Pizza Bianca");

    return flavors;
}

public int GetSizePrices(int num, List<string> menuList)
{
   // access to menuList
   var cnt = menuList.Count();
}
```

**Option 2 - Make it available as property**

```
public class Menu
{
    // A public property that is accessible in this class and from the outside
    public List<string> MenuList { get; set;}

    public Menu()
    {
        // Populate the property in the constructor of the class
        MenuList = new List<string>();
        MenuList.Add("Angus Steakhouse");
        MenuList.Add("Belly Buster");
        MenuList.Add("Pizza Bianca");
    }

    public int GetSizePrices(int num)
    {
        // your implementation details here...
        return MenuList.Count();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.